# How to generate n MarkovChain sequences of 25 transitions each

Tags: r, markov-chains

I have a transition matrix "T" and would like to produce 20 different sequences of 25 states each.

I have the `markovchain` package and have tried the following:

```
lapply(1:20,markovchainSequence(n = 25, markovchain = T, t0 = "In"))
```

but it says that `markovcahinsequence` is not a function. Is there a way around this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reproducible example can really help here but I think this does the job done! You may just need a bigger transition matrix?!

```
set.seed(123)
statesNames <- c("a", "b", "c") #easier with three states
t <- new("markovchain", states = statesNames,
         transitionMatrix = matrix(c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1),
                                   nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(statesNames, statesNames)))
mchain = function(n){
  markovchainSequence(n = n, markovchain = t, t0 = "a")
}
lapply(rep(25, each=20), mchain) # you may change 25 to desired number
```

Comment: Hi Majid, thank you very much for such a quick answer. You're of course right about the reproducible example. The baby started waking up so I thought it would be best to quickly click "post question" and come and edit it later.... It looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: No worries, anytime!